# Web service running an executable

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service that must run an executable.  To run the executable in C# I am using the Process object.

The service runs the executable when I run it locally through visual studio.  That is, it is converting a file and putting it in the output directory.

When I run the service on the production server the file does not get converted nor put into the Output directory.

I know that I am passing in the correct parameters to the executable because I had the service output the full path and parameter.  Then I pasted the full path and parameters into a command window on the server and it properly converted the file and placed it into the Output directory.

So I know the executable and its parameters are working on the server, but just not through the service.

I have confirmed in IIS that the service has Executable Permissions on "Scripts and Executables."

I am not sure what else to check or how else to test.

---

**[Edit] More Info:**

I had my web service call and run a file un-zipper.  I gave it the path to the executable and arguments for the archive I wanted un-zippped and the destination.  This worked fine.

When I point it back to the exe I need run it fails.  Here are two more points:

1) I have given Everyone full control of the folders, subfolders, and files.

2) The exe I need run is 16 bit.  Would that make a difference?

3) I was able to get it to return an error using proc.StandardError.  The error is:
"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way"

This is running on Windows Server 2003.

---

Any thoughts, ideas, or insight?

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: the user account under which IIS runs has to have the rights to the executable, its directory, and the "Output" directory.

Comment: Even though you have checked, my bet is still on permissions or path.

Comment: To repeat some deleted text, try running it under an admin account to see if that helps.

Comment: Does the executable have a UI at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark,

Ensure that you've got the path to the excecutable as per the fully qualified path on the server, i.e.:

```
e:\private\exe\businesscat1\yourexe.exe (etc,etc)
```

of course, it could also be something being invoked by the exe that isn't present that is being referenced.

jim